# retrive multi check box value by jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax, checked

i was searching on the web and stack but i cant found a way to solve my problem
so I hope someone can help me
i have a multi check box with same name "shopitem[]" and i want to check if check box are checked then send them value as array like "1,3,5,7" to php code with ajax

herere is my code:

```
<form id="ShopItemForm" class="ShopItemForm" method="post" name="ShopItemForm">
    <input class="ShopItem" checked="checked" name="ShopeItem[]" id="1" value="1" type="checkbox">1
    <input class="ShopItem" name="ShopeItem[]" id="2" value="2" type="checkbox">2
    <input class="ShopItem" checked="checked" name="ShopeItem[]" id="3" value="3" type="checkbox">3
    <input class="ShopItem" name="ShopeItem[]" id="4" value="4" type="checkbox">4
    <input class="ShopItem" name="ShopeItem[]" id="5" value="5" type="checkbox">5

    <input name="submitShopItem" value="submit" class="button button-push" id="submitShopItem" type="submit">
</form>

    $(function() {
    $("#submitShopItem").click(function(e) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    // put all checked box to array checkedArray
                    var shopItem = 
                    $("#shop-item-Loader").html('');
                    $("#shop-item-Loader").html('load');
                    $.ajax({
                            type: "POST",
                            url: "checked.php",
                            data: "act=shopItem&ShopItem="+checkedArray,
                            cache: false,
                            success: function(html){
                                alert(checkedArray);
                                $("#shop-item-Loader").html('');
                                $("#shop-item-Loader").append(html);
                            }
                    });
                });
            });
```

**i want to send all new checked value to ajax page like coma separated string**

Comment: First of all you have to fix the invalid html - `name="ShopeItem[] id=" 1"=""`

Comment: Absolutely!!!!!!! You have invalid html.

Comment: Pointers (as to HTML problems) unclosed attributes (particularly, it seems, the `name` and `id`) and, unless you've specified a doctype of `html`, your `id` values are invalid (since html <5 doesn't allow an `id` to start with a numeral).

Comment: When you say 'new checked values' do you mean you want only the checkboxes that the user checked (that *weren't* already/automatically checked on page-load)?

Comment: when i say new checked values i mean both automatically checked on page load and new user checked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var checkedArray = $("#ShopItemForm").find(":checked").map(function() {
    return this.value;
}).get();

console.log(checkedArray);
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/qB7M3/)

**Edit**
As suggested by @DavidThomas and the last sentence of the question:
To get a comma separated string of the checked elements you have to call `.join()` on `checkedArray`

```
checkedArray.join();
```

When used like here

```
data: "act=shopItem&ShopItem="+checkedArray,
```

that's done automatically

Comment: it send empty string like: ,,,

Comment: From the [API docs for `map()`](http://api.jquery.com/map/) you should be using `join()` as well.

Comment: I've used the wrong value (`id` instead of `value`) - Sorry for that. With a fixed html markup this should work

Comment: @DavidThomas Then the result would not be an array as the variable name suggests.

Comment: True, but the final line in the question ("[I] want to send all new checked value to ajax page like [comma] separated string") should probably supersede the implication of wanting an array. (Though admittedly the use of 'like' in that sentence is confusing.)

Answer (score 1):

See this : http://jsfiddle.net/Q2Kdt/

```
 $(function () {
 $("#submitShopItem").click(function (e) {
     e.preventDefault();
     var result = "";
     $('input[type=checkbox]').each(function (e) {
         if ($(this).is(':checked')) result = result + $(this).val() + ", ";
     });
     alert(result);
 });
 });
```

Or check by name itself:  http://jsfiddle.net/Q2Kdt/2/

```
$(function () {
 $("#submitShopItem").click(function (e) {
     e.preventDefault();
     var result = "";
     $("input[name*='ShopeItem[]']").filter(':checked').each(function (e) {
        result = result + $(this).val() + ", ";
     });
     alert(result);
 });
});
```